# Не корректная сортировка 2d массива методом пузырька

Tags: c++, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

```
#include <iostream>
void InitializeArray(const int, char *, int, int);
void DisplayArray(const int, char *);
void Sort_bubble(const int, char *);
void Swap(char &, char &);
int main() {
  system("clear");
  int min = int('!'), max = int('@'), size = 5;
  char arr[size][size];
  printf("\t\tGenerated array\n");
  InitializeArray(size, *arr, min, max);
  DisplayArray(size, *arr);
  printf("\n\t\tSorted array\n");
  Sort_bubble(size, *arr);
  DisplayArray(size, *arr);
  return 0;
}
void InitializeArray(const int size, char *arr, int min, int max) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      *(arr + i * size + j) = min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
    }
  }
}
void DisplayArray(const int size, char *arr) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      printf("%c ", *(arr + i * size + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
void Sort_bubble(const int size, char *array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
        Swap(array[j], array[j + 1]);
}
void Swap(char &a, char &b) {
  char temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

Проблема в том, что программа сортирует лишь до нулевого элемента первой строки.
Пример выполнения программы:[image: В данном случае посортировало до элемента '@']

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, как именно должен сортироваться *двумерный* массив. Это могут быть отсортированные строки, столбцы, весь массив построчно, постолбцово, змейкой :) Нет точного ТЗ — ответ один: ХЗ!!

Comment: Должен быть отсортирован весь массив по возрастанию значений

Comment: Ну так поскольку `char arr[size][size];` одна большая одномерная "кишка", просто сортируйте как одномерный массив `char [size*size]`...

Comment: оно так не работает

Comment: @Илья Работает, если вы внимательно вчитаетесь, и вместо  циклов до size сделаете циклы до указанного значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно сортировка у вас написана. Правда с ошибкой выхода за пределы массива.

```
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) // если size реальный размер массива
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1])  // то array[j + 1] - выход за его пределы на последней итерации
// должно быть
for (int j = 0; j < size-1; j++)
```

С учетом того, что двумерный массив `arr[size][size]` на самом деле в памяти хранится линейно как одномерный `arr[size*size]` (как и написал Harry), просто измените граничное значение, до которого будет идти сортировка с `size` до `size*size`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size*size; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < size*size-1; j++) // поскольку вы используете array[j + 1] 
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
        Swap(array[j], array[j + 1]);
```

Ну и немного оптимизации, чтобы не проходить повторно по уже отсортированному куску массива

```
for (int i = size*size-1; i > 0 ; i--)
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
         Swap(array[j], array[j + 1]);
```